# Django: TypeError at /categories/ sequence item 0: expected str instance, Category found

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to code an e-phrasebook with Django to help people learn languages. Or actually a new version of an older one with new features. Anyway I'm badly stuck on the first meters here.

I have added some objects to the database and want to show them at the "categories" url. The first url http://127.0.0.1:8000/ works nicely and gives me a wonderful hello world. However, I need to connect the new app to the project, and when I try to open the url of the app http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/, the browsers gives me this:

```
TypeError at /categories/
sequence item 0: expected str instance, Category found
```

My console complains about app's view.py, and within that about line 9 `output = ', '.join(categories)`. I can't find anything wrong with it. Here is the whole views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Category


def category_list(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    output = ', '.join(categories)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

This is the app's url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.category_list),
]
```

Here is the main url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^categories/', include('phrasebooktwo.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.hello_world),
]
```

Here is the project tree:

```
bigboy_phrasebook
├── bigboy_phrasebook
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── views.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── phrasebooktwo
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── admin.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── models.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
    │   └── views.cpython-35.pyc
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-35.pyc
    │       └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

How do I get my categories page working? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the **str**() or **repr**() or any other method which returns a string on the categories object before you use join(). Let me explain this by taking simple example:

```
class Category:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


items = [Category('jam')]
out = ', '.join(items)
print(out)
```

If you run this code, you will get "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Category found"

So, you have to modify the code as below:

```
class Category:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


items = [Category('jam').__str__()]
out = ', '.join(items)
print(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def category_list(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    output = ', '.join(categories)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Here `categories` is `queryset` object So when you add this `join` method it iterate as single `instance` from `queryset` and `instance` is objects of **Model**.So that will not work **concat** with `join` method. Use str method in join method like below way

```
def category_list(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    output = ', '.join(str(categories))
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, silly me. I was doing this based on a tutorial at www.teamtreehouse.com and I was sure that I had watched the whole video "First App View" but I had not. Sorry for the trouble people, and thanks for your help anyway! The teacher had intentionally written code that didn't work first, and then explained the right way to do it with this code, that in my own app looks like this:

```
def category_list(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    output = ', '.join([str(category) for category in categories])
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Now it works. I have to remember to finish watching these videos in the future.